# Data handling on multiple Heart rate files

Tags: heartbeat

I have been collecting the Heart rates of 12 calves who each received an anesthetic through four different routes of administration. I now have 48 txt files of this format:

Time    HRbpm

0:00:01.7   97

0:00:02.3   121

0:00:02.8   15

...         ...

HR was recorded for around 2hours. The Time column was dependent of the monitor, resulting in inconsistent time intervals between two measures.

The txt files are named as follows: 6133_IM_27.00.txt
With 6133 being the ID, IM the route and 27.00 the time (min:min.s:s) at which the treatment was injected.

My first goal is to have all the HR data so I can do an outlier analysis.

Then, I would like to include all this data in a single data frame that would look like this:

```
data.frame(ID=c(6133,6133,6133,6133,"...",6134,6134,"..."),
           Route = c("IM","IM","IM","IM","...","SC","SC","..."),
           time=c(0, 10, 20, 30,"...",0,10,"..."),
           HR=c(160, 150, 145, 130,"...",162,158,"..."))
```

Time column going from 0 to 120 in 10min increments.
Each HR of this df would represent the mean of the HR values for the preceding minute for a given time (e.g. for time = 30, HR would represent the mean between 29 and 30 minutes for a given ID/Route combination).

I'm fairly new to R, so I've been having trouble just knowing by what angle starting on that problem. Any help would be welcome.

Thanks,

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles on this post, here's what I've done, seems to be working.

```
library(plyr)
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)

setwd("/directory")

filelist = list.files(pattern = ".*.txt")
datalist = lapply(filelist, read.delim) 
for (i in 1:length(datalist))
{datalist[[i]][3] = filelist[i]}
df = do.call("rbind", datalist)

attach(df)
out_lowHR = quantile(HRbpm,0.25)-1.5*IQR(HRbpm)
out_highHR = quantile(HRbpm,0.75)+1.5*IQR(HRbpm) #outliers thresholds: 60 and 200

dfc = subset(df,HRbpm>=60 & HRbpm<=200)
(length(df$HRbpm)-length(dfc$HRbpm))/length(df$HRbpm)*100 #8.6% of values excluded
df = dfc

df$ID = substr(df$V3,4,7)
df$ROA = substr(df$V3,9,11)
df$ti = substr(df$V3,13,17)
df$Time = as.POSIXct(as.character(df$Time), format="%H:%M:%S")
df$ti = as.POSIXct(as.character(df$ti), format="%M.%S")
df$t = as.numeric(df$Time-df$ti)

m=60
meanHR = ddply(df, c("ROA","ID"), summarise,
      mean0  =  mean(HRbpm[t>-60*m & t <=0]),
      mean10 = mean(HRbpm[t>9*m & t <=10*m]),
      mean20 = mean(HRbpm[t>19*m & t <=20*m]),
      mean30 = mean(HRbpm[t>29*m & t <=30*m]),
      mean45 = mean(HRbpm[t>44*m & t <=45*m]),
      mean60 = mean(HRbpm[t>59*m & t <=60*m]),
      mean90 = mean(HRbpm[t>89*m & t <=90*m]),
      mean120 = mean(HRbpm[t>119*m & t <=120*m]))
meanHR = melt(meanHR)
meanHR$time = as.numeric(gsub("mean", "", meanHR$variable))

ggplot(meanHR, aes(x = time, y = value, col = ROA))+
  geom_smooth()+
  theme_classic()
```